# No route matches in rails ?customize privilege of Action of controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models `Follow user` and `Master`.

Follow user can `show, edit` and Master can `add,edit,show and delete` the follow user.

I use `authenticate_user!` for admin `add, edit, show and delete`

and `authenticate_user!` for followuser `edit, show`

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:new, :create,:show ,:edit, :destroy]

#routes.rb
resources :folusers
resources :masters
```

**When creating a new Follow user, occurs this error:**

> No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"folusers", :id=>nil},
>   missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: How're you calling the folusers#edit action?

Comment: This `:id=>nil` is the problem. See where it is coming from.

Comment: @Sebastian Palma caling use `edit_foluser_path(@foluser)`

Comment: `:id` is automatically on database when create new follow user

Comment: What's the value of @foluser?, might it be nil?

Answer (score 0):

Take another look at where you're accessing this route. It looks like you're not routing to "new" (which DOES NOT require an id param). Instead, you seem to be routing to "edit", which DOES require an id (the id of the FollowUser to edit).

Comment: i use but when remove `authenticate_user!` work but i need use it .